# 'on board' v.s. 'on board of'

Tags: grammaticality

I came across this sentence from [John Adams by David McCullough](https://books.google.fr/books?id=s-sTrTHz8oMC&pg=PT415&lpg=PT415&dq=crossing%20the%20channel%20on%20board%20the%20Dover%20packet%20days%20later&source=bl&ots=Acy9T06fYq&sig=8I8_Fy6IM4UnaF6bvdOR4pRpCEs&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=crossing%20the%20channel%20on%20board%20the%20Dover%20packet%20days%20later&f=false)

> Crossing the Channel ***on board*** the Dover packet days later, Abigail offered to share the family's cabin with a desperately seasick young man who, in gratitude for her kindness, gave her two songbirds of his own.

Would it be more grammatically correct to write 'on board of/aboard the Dover packet'? (As according to [thefreedictioanry.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Aboard), when used as prep., 'aboard' means ' on board of;on;in'.)

Comment: 'aboard' is ok, but 'on board of' is not grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "on board" translates to be on/in a ship, aircraft, or any other physical conveyance. Adding the preposition "of" after "on board" results in a grammatical error and is unnecessary.    In the quoted text, the phrase "on board" is accurately used, followed by the definite article "the."

Consider the following example sentences:

1. After a quick assessment, he was taken **on board the** aircraft.
2. It was unclear exactly how many people were **on board the** chartered aircraft.
3. Mr. Kelly said the 770 passengers **on board the** ship were preparing to disembark.
4. Representatives of both organisations attended a special event **on board the** Irish naval ship.

Note that none of these examples have employed the preposition "of" after "on board" to suggest getting in/on a physical conveyance.

The phrase "on board" and the adverb "aboard" has the same meaning and is sometimes interchangeable depending on the context.

Source: [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on_board)

Comment: So when are they not interchangeable?